# Ubuntu Linux and SCO UNIX OpenServer

Tags: linux, executable, sco, emulation

Can Ubuntu Linux run SCO UNIX OpenServer 5.0.7 *applications* like filePro?  Can I use CTAR to copy application directories from a CTAR backup tape to Linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly there is a binary emulation support that is available to the [Linux kernel though it needs to be compiled in](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.sco.misc/sco-emulator-for-linux/1262337).  I've always found though that it is better to port the application or run a native alternative then try running through an emulator.

Comment: This binary emulation was dropped a while ago, before Ubuntu even existed. This has been discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7884).

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it, but you might have [more luck with NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/compat.html), which has more powerful binary emulation features. It claims to support SCO UNIX binaries; you might need to supply your own libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Sco unix are incompatible binaries,so the answer is not.
Is possible to emulate the entire sco system in Virtualbox(some version like 5,6 and even some old 3.2 works fine),but not using a sco binary
or entire app on linux.
Never heard of ctar,if you mean tar,the answer is yes,tar archives are portable between unix system,one of the few thing wich work on all unix os!