# How to get the last argument to a /bin/sh function

Tags: shell-script

What's a better way to implement `print_last_arg`?

```
#!/bin/sh

print_last_arg () {
    eval "echo \${$#}"  # this hurts
}

print_last_arg foo bar baz
# baz
```

(If this were, say, `#!/usr/bin/zsh` instead of `#!/bin/sh` I'd know what to do.  My problem is finding a reasonable way to implement this for `#!/bin/sh`.)

EDIT: The above is only a silly example.  My goal is not to *print* the last argument, but rather to have a way to refer to the last argument within a shell function.

---

EDIT2: **I apologize for such an unclearly worded question.**  I hope to get it right this time.

If this were `/bin/zsh` instead of `/bin/sh`, I could write something like this

```
#!/bin/zsh

print_last_arg () {
    local last_arg=$argv[$#]
    echo $last_arg
}
```

The expression `$argv[$#]` is an example of what I described in my first EDIT as *a way to refer to the last argument within a shell function*.

Therefore, I really should have written my original example like this:

```
print_last_arg () {
    local last_arg=$(eval "echo \${$#}")   # but this hurts even more
    echo $last_arg
}
```

...to make it clear that what I'm after is a less awful thing to put to the right of the assignment.

Note, however, that in all the examples, the last argument is accessed *non-destructively*.  IOW, the accessing of the last argument leaves the positional arguments as a whole unaffected.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/117549 points out the various possibilities of #!/bin/sh -- can you narrow it down any?

Comment: i do like the edit, but perhaps you may have also noticed that there is an answer here which offers a non-destructive means of referencing the last argument...? you should not equate `var=$( eval echo \${$#})` to `eval var=\${$#}` - the two are nothing alike.

Comment: Not sure I get your last note but almost all answers provided so far are non destructive in the sense they do preserve the running script arguments. Only `shift` and `set -- ...` based solutions might be destructive unless used in functions where they are harmless too.

Comment: @jlliagre - but they are still destructive in the main - they require creating disposable contexts so they can destroy to discover. but... if you get a second context anyway - why not just get the one allows you to index? is there something wrong with using the tool intended for the job? interpreting shell expansions as expandable input is eval's job. and there's nothing significantly different about doing `eval "var=\${$#}"` when compared to `var=${arr[evaled index]}` except that `$#` is a guaranteed safe value. why copy the whole set then destroy it when you could just index it directly?

Comment: @mikeserv A for loop done in the main part of the shell is leaving all arguments unchanged. I agree looping all arguments is very un-optimized, especially if thousands of them are passed to the shell and I agree too that directly accessing the last argument with the proper index is the best answer (and I don't understand why it was downvoted) but beyond that, there is nothing really destructive and no extra context created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval printf %s${1+"'\n' \"the last arg is \${$#"\}\"}
```

...will either print the string *`the last arg is`* followed by a *<space>*, the value of the last argument, and a trailing *<newline>* if there is at least 1 argument, or else, for zero arguments, it will print nothing at all.

If you did:

```
eval ${1+"lastarg=\${$#"\}}
```

...then either you would assign the value of the last argument to the shell variable `$lastarg` if there is at least 1 argument, or you would do nothing at all. Either way, you would do it safely, and it ought to be portable even to ye Olde Bourne shell, I think.

Here's another one that would work similarly, though it does require copying the whole arg array twice *(and requires a `printf` in `$PATH` for the Bourne shell)*:

```
if   [ "${1+:}" ]
then set "$#" "$@" "$@"
     shift    "$1"
     printf %s\\n "$1"
     shift
fi
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34745/discussion-on-answer-by-mikeserv-how-to-get-the-last-argument-to-a-bin-sh-funct).

Comment: FYI, your first suggestion fails under the legacy bourne shell with a  "bad substitution" error if no arguments are present. Both remaining ones work as expected.

Comment: @jillagre - thank you. i wasn't so sure about that top one - but was pretty sure of the other two. it was just meant to be demonstrative of how arguments might be accessed by reference inline. preferably a function would open with something like `${1+":"} return` right away - because who wants it doing anything or risking side effects of any kind if was called for nothing? Math is pretty for the same - if you can be sure you can expand a positive integer you can `eval` all day. `$OPTIND` is great for it.

Answer (score 4):

Given the example of the opening post (positional arguments without spaces):

```
print_last_arg foo bar baz
```

For the default `IFS=' \t\n'`, how about:

```
args="$*" && printf '%s\n' "${args##* }"
```

For a safer expansion of `"$*"`, set IFS (per @StéphaneChazelas):

```
( IFS=' ' args="$*" && printf '%s\n' "${args##* }" )
```

But the above will fail if your positional arguments can contain spaces. In that case, use this instead:

```
for a in "$@"; do : ; done && printf '%s\n' "$a"
```

Note that these techniques avoid the use of `eval` and do not have side-effects.

Tested at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: The first one fail if last argument contain space.

Comment: Note that the first one also did not work in pre-POSIX shell

Comment: @cuonglm Well spotted, your correct observation is incorporated now.

Comment: It also assumes the first character of `$IFS` is a space.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  I considered IFS - as far as I can tell the first character will be a space by default in Posix shells - is this correct? That is why I did not include it.

Comment: It will be if there's no $IFS in the environment, unspecified otherwise. But because you need to set IFS virtually everytime you use the split+glob operator (leave an expansion unquoted), one approach with dealing with IFS is to set it whenever you need it. It wouldn't harm having `IFS=' '` here just to make it clear that it's being used for the expansion of `"$*"`.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is just over 2 years old, I thought I’d share a somewhat compacter option.

```
print_last_arg () {
    echo "${@:${#@}:${#@}}"
}
```

Let’s run it

```
print_last_arg foo bar baz
baz
```

Bash [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

**Edit**

Even more concise:
`echo "${@: -1}"`

(Mind the space)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script)

Tested on macOS 10.12.6 but should also return the last argument on most available *nix flavors...

Hurts much less `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Even better would be: `echo "${*: -1}"` which `shellcheck` won't complain about.

Comment: This won't work with a plain POSIX sh, `${array:n:m:}` is an extension. (the question did explicitly mention `/bin/sh`)

Comment: @TomHale Shellcheck now complains about this answer: `SC3057: In POSIX sh, string indexing is undefined.`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplistic way:

```
print_last_arg () {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
  then
    s=$(( $# - 1 ))
  else
    s=0
  fi
  shift "$s"
  echo "$1"
}
```

(updated based on @cuonglm's point that the original failed when passed no arguments; this now echos a blank line -- change that behavior in the `else` clause if desired)

Comment: This required using /usr/xpg4/bin/sh on Solaris; let me know if Solaris #!/bin/sh is a requirement.

Comment: This question is not about a specific script I'm trying to write, but rather a general how-to.  I'm looking for a good recipe for this.  Of course, the more portable, the better.

Comment: the $(( )) math fails in Solaris /bin/sh; use something like: shift \`expr $# - 1\` if that's required.

Comment: alternatively for Solaris /bin/sh, `echo "$# - 1" | bc`

Comment: @JeffSchaller: This fail if there's no arguments.

Comment: updated, though I had to work past the philosophical question of "what's the last element of an empty list?" as well as resign myself that I couldn't reliably count on the a?b:c ternary operator inside $(( ))

Comment: @JeffSchaller: It's not the philosophical question, it's about the negative impact it gave to your script. Also note that `$((...))` did not work in old Bourne shell.

Comment: Yes, I had to ask OP how portable it needed to be. I did assume at first that they were passing a non-empty list.

Comment: jeff - `shift "$(($#?$#-1:0))"; printf "%s${1+\n}" "$@"` would always do the right thing nicely,

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to write, but it failed on the 2nd shell I tried -- NetBSD, which apparently is an Almquist shell that doesn't support it :(

Comment: wow. does it handle `$(( ${#} ? ` differently as `zsh` does? or does it handle `$(( ${#} &&`... differently? or am i way off and it wasn't even the math which broke it?

Comment: Probably this would work: `${1+":"} return; shift "$((${#}-1))"; printf %s\\n "$@"`

Comment: [chat room created](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101482/how-to-get-the-last-argument-to-a-bin-sh-function)

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; do
  shift
done

printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

(This approach also works in old Bourne shell)

With other standard tools:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ARGV[ARGC-1]}' "$@"
```

(This won't work with old `awk`, which did not have `ARGV`)

Comment: Where there's still a Bourne shell, `awk` could also be the old awk that didn't have `ARGV`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Agree. At least it worked with Brian Kernighan's own version. Do you have any ideal?

Comment: This erase the arguments. How to keep them?.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Use the `awk` approach, or use other plain `for` loop like other did, or passing them to a function.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with any POSIX compliant shell and will work too with the pre POSIX legacy Solaris Bourne shell:

```
do=;for do do :;done;printf "%s\n" "$do"
```

and here is a function based on the same approach:

```
print_last_arg()
  if [ "$*" ]; then
    for do do :;done
    printf "%s\n" "$do"
  else
    echo
  fi
```

PS: don't tell me I forgot the curly braces around the function body ;-)

Comment: You forgot the curly braces around the function body ;-).

Comment: @BinaryZebra I warned you ;-) I didn't forget them. The braces are surprisingly optional here.

Comment: @jlliagre I, indeed, was warned ;-) :P ......  And: certainly !

Comment: Which part of the syntax spec allows this?

Comment: @TomHale The shell grammar rules allows both a missing `in ...` in a `for` loop and an no curly braces around an `if`statement used as function body. See `for_clause` and `compound_command` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/.

Comment: The `do do` also had me puzzled, but I guess the first `do` could be replaced with anything.

Comment: @TomHale It can indeed. I could also have written `for for do :; done;printf "%s\n" "$for"` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

From ["Unix - Frequently Asked Questions"](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-12.html)

(1)

```
unset last
if    [ $# -gt 0 ]
then  eval last=\${$#}
fi
echo  "$last"
```

If the number of arguments could be zero, then argument zero `$0` (usually the name of the script) will be assigned to `$last`. That's the reason for the if.

(2)

```
unset last
for   last
do    :
done
echo  "$last"
```

(3)

```
for     i
do
        third_last=$second_last
        second_last=$last
        last=$i
done
echo    "$last"
```

To avoid printing an empty line when there are no arguments, replace the `echo "$last"` for:

```
${last+false} || echo "${last}"
```

A zero argument count is avoided by `if [ $# -gt 0 ]`.

This is a not an exact copy of what is in the linked in the page, some improvements were added.

Answer (score 0):

A simple concept, no arithmetic, no loop, no **eval**, just functions.
Remember that Bourne shell had no arithmetic (needed external `expr`). If wanting to get an arithmetic free, `eval` free choice, this is an option.  Needing functions means SVR3 or above (no overwrite of parameters).
Look below for a more robust version with printf.

```
printlast(){
    shift "$1"
    echo "$1"
}

printlast "$#" "$@"          ### you may use ${1+"$@"} here to allow
                             ### a Bourne empty list of arguments,
                             ### but wait for a correct solution below.
```

This structure to call `printlast` is **fixed**, the arguments need to be set in the list of shell arguments `$1`, `$2`, etc. (the argument stack) and the call done as given.

If the list of arguments needs to be changed, just set them:

```
set -- o1e t2o t3r f4u
printlast "$#" "$@"
```

Or create an easier to use function (`getlast`) that could allow generic arguments (but not as fast, arguments are passed two times).

```
getlast(){ printlast "$#" "$@"; }
getlast o1e t2o t3r f4u
```

Please note that arguments (of `getlast`, or all included in `$@` for printlast) could have spaces, newlines, etc. But not NUL.

### Better

This version does not print `0` when the list of arguments is empty,
and use the more robust printf (fall back to `echo` if external `printf` is not available for old shells).

```
printlast(){ shift  "$1"; printf '%s' "$1"; }
getlast  ()  if     [ $# -gt 0 ]
             then   printlast "$#" "$@"
                    echo    ### optional if a trailing newline is wanted.
             fi
### The {} braces were removed on purpose.

getlast 1 2 3 4    # will print 4
```

#### Using EVAL.

If the Bourne shell is even older and there are no functions, or if for some reason using eval is the only option:

To print the value:

```
if    [ $# -gt 0 ]
then  eval printf "'1%s\n'" \"\$\{$#\}\"
fi
```

To set the value in a variable:

```
if    [ $# -gt 0 ]
then  eval 'last_arg='\"\$\{$#\}\"
fi
```

If that needs to be done in a function, the arguments need to be copied to the function:

```
print_last_arg () {
    local last_arg                ### local only works on more modern shells.
    eval 'last_arg='\"\$\{$#\}\"
    echo "last_arg3=$last_arg"
}

print_last_arg "$@"               ### Shell arguments are sent to the function.
```

Comment: it is better but it says doesn't use a loop - but it does. an array copy *is a loop*. and with two functions it uses *two* loops. also - is there some reason iterating the entire array should be preferred to indexing it with `eval`?

Comment: Do you see any `for loop` or `while loop`?

Comment: [yes i do](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/array.c?h=bash-4.4-testing)

Comment: That doesn't mean it doesn't do them.

Comment: By your standard, I guess that all code has loops, even a `echo "Hello"` has loops as the CPU has to read memory locations in a loop. Again: my code has no added loops.

Comment: you needlessly copy an entire array just to destroy it to enable you to do what otherwise might be done with a simple index. You describe this method choice as *simple* and *without loops*, when, in fact, in order to do it, the interpreter for your language must loop unnecessarily several times. It's misleading, and bad form. And why bother arguing with me about it? If I say nothing of substance you ought merely to ignore it, but if a comment on your answer offers valid criticism don't *fight* it - *fix* it.

Comment: Why should I ignore you? The only people I have been taught to ignore is crazy people. Are you crazy? If so, then yes, I should ignore you. I am only answering to your (clearly) incorrect statements. Statements that only mislead unsuspecting users. For them, I try to clear your mistakes. Yours is not valid criticism. And note that there have been five other points that I have already proven correct. This is just one more. You keep pushing for a meaning that is not inside what is written.

Comment: The function, as requested by the OP, must receive "$@" (the arguments). As I have already said, and you keep forgetting (because it fits your goals), the answers from jlliagre, Jeff Schaller, and @terdon also copy the arguments to a function. And the answer from cuonglm destroy the argument array. Why do you pick my answer as your only target? Solve the problems in all the other answers as well. And frankly: Why don't you go fix the whole internet? It is full of mistakes and flaws. And leave alone this correct answer. It is you who is wrong, not this answer.

Comment: I have already said this: *none of the other answers which copy the array claim to do anything but*. Your answer is misleading. That is all I am saying.

Comment: My answer does not have added a `for`, `while`, or `until` loop. That's a fact. Your interpretation is the one misleading.

Comment: If so, then *ignore me*. But I contend that it is *not* - and only care because it could be a good answer and only isnt for sake of your pride as near as i can tell. Whether or not your answer *adds* shell loops is immaterial to the ***fact*** that its primary method is a *loop* and that it opens with a statement which is directly contradictory to the ***fact*** of the matter.

Comment: I really do not care about your opinion of good or bad, it has been proven wrong several times already. Again: my code has no `for`, `while` or `until` loops. Do you see any `for` `while` or `until` loop written in the code?. No?, then just accept the fact, embrace it and learn.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on all systems with `perl` installed (so most UNICES):

```
print_last_arg () {
    printf '%s\0' "$@" | perl -0ne 's/\0//;$l=$_;}{print "$l\n"'
}
```

The trick is to use `printf` to add a `\0` after each shell argument and then `perl`'s `-0` switch which sets its record separator to NULL. Then we iterate over the input, remove the `\0` and saving each NULL-terminated line as `$l`. The `END` block (that's what the `}{` is) will be executed after all input has been read so will print the last "line": the last shell argument.

Comment: @mikeserv ah, true, I hadn't tested with a newline in any but the last argument. The edited version should work for pretty much anything but is probably too convoluted for such a simple task.

Comment: yeah, calling up an outside executable *(if it's not already part of the logic)* is, to me, a little heavy-handed. but if the point is to pass that argument on to `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` then it could be valuable information anyway. still you can do the same with `sed -z` for up-to-date GNU versions.

Comment: why did you get downvoted? this was good... i thought?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using recursion. No idea how POSIX compliant this is though...

```
print_last_arg()
{
    if [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
        shift
        echo $( print_last_arg "$@" )
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478385/get-last-element-of-argv-arguments-array-without-eval?noredirect=1#comment874510_478385) suggested to use the very elegant:

```
echo "${@:$#}"
```