# Get last element of $@ / argv / arguments array without eval

Tags: bash

If I do:

```
set a b c
```

How do I access the last element of `$@`, namely `c`?

I've initially thought to subscript the `$@` array:

```
"${@[$#-1]}"
```

But:

```
bash: ${@[$#-1]}: bad substitution
```

I eventually came up with:

```
eval echo "\$$#"
```

Is there a way to get the last element of `$@` without `eval`?

Is the only way to first copy it to another array and access `${copy[-1]}`?

Comment: At least for bash: ["`echo "${@: -1}"` (Mind the space)"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437050/70524)

Comment: Cheers @muru. Even better would be: `echo "${*: -1}"` which `shellcheck` won't complain about.

Comment: @TomHale, hmm, I don't get a complaint for `echo "${@: -1}"`. What does it complain to you about? I'd go with `"${@: -1}"` (or `"${@:$#}"`) just because `"$@"` is so much more common. Seeing `"$*"` makes me stop and think what the code is doing...

Comment: @ikkachu I was wrong about `shellcheck`. I prefer your `"${@:$#}"` as most readable. Cheers!

Comment: "${@:$#}" is not portable like all similar constructs. If `shellcheck` is intended to mark non-POSIX syntax, it should complain.

Comment: @schily shellcheck has sh, ksh and bash modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ilkkachu suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478385/get-last-element-of-argv-arguments-array-without-eval?noredirect=1#comment874510_478385) the very readable:

```
echo "${@:$#}"
```

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the edit - sorry for getting your name wrong.

Comment: Well, everyone seems to get it wrong here :D (the ell does get a bit hidden within the vertical lines). So, no problem.

Comment: @TomHale This raises SC2124 ( https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2124 ): "Assigning an array to a string".

Comment: @Johannnes that warning seems redundant. If it's a one element array, and can only ever be one element, what exactly is the issue? I've raised some issues with shellcheck in the past, and sheet you do so in this case. What does it say with * instead?

Comment: @TomHale, switching to `${*:$#}` gets rid of the shellcheck warning.