# Shell Script Execution with Bash and without bash on command line

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, apache-hive

I have a shell script that reads data from a file and stores it into an array.
When i execute the script like `bash scriptname.sh` i dont get any errors 
but when i execute it using `sh scriptname.sh` i get errors like array deceleration not found some syntax errors like parentheses are expected.

why differences are coming between these two approaches??

Comment: In particular see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145523/135943).  Since you're using Ubuntu, `sh` is really `dash`, not `bash`.  So this means you have some "bashisms" in your script.

Comment: Thanks .The links mentioned by you tells that there are difference between the features of these shells.