# Set LS_COLORS in Alpine

Tags: shell, ls, colors, alpine-linux

I am trying to set the directory colors in alpine to be white.

I tried to create ~/.profile with `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;44:' ; export LS_COLORS` in it.  But it had no effect.

I see many examples out there for doing this in BASH.  But Alpine uses SH.

**How can I change the color of directories in Alpine?**

Comment: Are you sure that `ls` in Alpine respects `LS_COLORS`?  Can you set that manually in the shell after you log in and see the expected color change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alpine uses SH.

Incorrect.  Alpine Linux uses BusyBox, and the *Almquist shell* variant that is part of BusyBox.

Which is the root of the issue.  BusyBox `ls` in recent versions has a `--color` option, which is documented in its user manual (q.v.).  Its colour choices are hardwired into the program, and not configurable with an environment variable.

If you really want an `ls` command with colours that you can configure with an environment variable, you will have to install some other `ls` command.

## Further reading

- [What does it mean to be "sh compatible"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/5132)

Comment: huh.  OK.  I did not know that.  I assumed it was sh because when I connect to it I launch `/bin/sh`.  Either way, it sounds like I have to run `ls --color=never` each time I want to see the directories.

Answer (score 0):

JdeBP’s answer is absolutely right. Customizing colours is not possible in BusyBox `ls`. However, you can *disable* colours by using an alias:

```
export ls='ls --color=never'
```

can be added to /etc/profile or another similar configuration file.
That way, you don’t have to type `--color=never` every time you use `ls`.

I realize that it’s not the solution you were hoping for, but it will make it easier to see directories (based on your comment, I believe that’s the issue?).