# Why sh has a symbolic link to dash or bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arch-linux

I found that sh is a symbolic link to bash

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May  9 15:23 /bin/sh -> bash
```

I tried to find a reason and i found out that [bash is a implementation of sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) and can behave like sh or POSIX. So scripts with #!/bin/sh are invoked by bash with a try to mimic behaviour of sh. And there are other impletations too like dash, csh etc.
While reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717870/why-does-bin-sh-behave-differently-to-bin-bash-even-if-one-points-to-the-other) when invoked with /bin/sh bash moves to POSIX mode after reading startup files. I don't have much experience with shells but as these answers are stating : there is no sh by default in some systems and bash or any other shell is doing the homework for sh. And i want some expert opinion on this matter.

1. When invoked with sh Bash enters POSIX mode after reading startup files. But what are these startup files?
2. So the point is if bash is doing the work of sh in my system than does this means that there is no sh in my system and all the scripts with sh is invoked by bash or any other shell to which sh points to.

Comment: You may find the answers at [What does it mean to be “sh compatible”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145522/what-does-it-mean-to-be-sh-compatible) and links therein to be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the original Unix systems, `sh` was a specific program with specific behavior.  It was often contrasted with other shells which came along later, such as `csh` and `ksh`.

However, POSIX standardized the behavior of `sh`, and on modern open source operating systems, usually `sh` is actually some other implementation, and it merely has a mode which provides the POSIX behavior.  For example, on FreeBSD, we'd refer to `ash` as `sh`; on OpenBSD, `sh` and `ksh` are the same program, and on Linux, you'll often find `bash` or `dash` as `sh` (although Debian permits many others, including `zsh`, `mksh`, `posh`, and potentially others).

In such a case, it's true that whatever shell is being invoked as `sh` is doing the work that `sh` would do because there's no independent `sh` program on those systems.  It's merely a mode that provides the POSIX behavior.

In that POSIX mode, the startup files that are read are `/etc/profile` and `$HOME/.profile` for login shells and the contents of the file pointed to by `$ENV` for interactive shells, if that environment variable is not present.  Shell-specific files are not invoked.

Comment: Note that most shells do emulate the mandated POSIX sh behaviour when invoked as sh.

Answer (score 3):

> When invoked with sh Bash enters POSIX mode after reading startup files. But what are these startup files?

The startup files also depend on if it was started as `sh` or not.

- In normal mode, as an interactive shell: `/etc/profile` and the first of `~/.bash_profile`/ `~/.bash_login`/`~/.profile` if it's a login shell, and just `~/.bashrc` if not a login shell.
- In `sh` mode: `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` if a login shell; and whatever the environment variable `$ENV` points to if interactive. In particular, it doesn't read the `~/.bash*` files in `sh` mode.

See the manual for the actual details, it's not exactly simple: [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

> So the point is if bash is doing the work of sh in my system than does this means that there is no sh in my system and all the scripts with sh is invoked by bash or any other shell to which sh points to.

I'm not exactly sure what the question is, or what the other shell would be when Bash does the work of sh. But anyway, if `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/bash` (or is another copy of Bash), then all scripts using the `#!/bin/sh` hashbang, and commands started with e.g. the `system()` library call in C would run using Bash. But that's fine, since Bash is well capable of being compatible with those uses.

Also note that `csh` belongs to a different family, and is not compatible with POSIX sh.